# Google Sheets Query - Issue grouping rows into the header row

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Whenever I query a large amount of data, it bunches up several rows into the header row row.

I've tried

```
=QUERY('Keywords-Raw'!A:O,"SELECT A,B,G,L,O WHERE L MATCHES '"&A1&"'",1)
```

which removes the header, but I need the header.

I've also tried

```
=QUERY('Keywords-Raw'!A:O,"SELECT A,B,G,L,O WHERE L MATCHES '"&A1&"' OFFSET 1"), but this only skips a row that I'll need.
```

[image]

I don't want it to be grouped like that. I want it to be like the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to write "MATCHES" not "="

```
=QUERY('Keywords-Raw'!A:O,"SELECT A,B,G,L,O WHERE L = '"&A1&"'",1)
```

Also, if you do not want column labels, use the LABEL keyword

```
=QUERY('Keywords-Raw'!A:O,"SELECT A,B,G,L,O WHERE L = '"&A1&"' LABEL A '', B '', G '', L '', O '' ",1)
```